# Is there any way to convert a ShaderSignal value to a normalized ScalarValue on Spark AR?

Tags: reactive-programming, patch, spark-ar-studio

I've simulated a perlin noise generator on patches using a noise texture, loop animation and texture transform. I've converted the resulting texture from RGB to HSL and catch the Luminance value to use it as a positionModifier for a Particle System, but a I've got a "Patch received a ShaderGeneric signal, when the type expected was Scalar".

I would like to take that Luminance value and convert it to a Normalized (0-1) value

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your patch?